# Streaming Data to Sound Card Using C on Windows

Tags: c, windows, signal-processing, openal, directsound

As part of a university project I have to do some signal processing and would like to output the results using the PC sound card. The software has to be written in C and needs to work with Windows (preferably 7 and XP).

I have found code examples for outputting .wav and similar files, but I am interested in continuously outputting data rather than outputting from files. It is likely that the data for output will be presented as an array although some sound APIs seem to have their own ways of dealing with buffers.

Any suggestions would be great, as would code examples or even the best API. I have looked at DirectSound and OpenAL but am still unsure how to get started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) is a C library that should suit your needs. There is a [tutorial](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/tutorial_start.html) to get you started.

> PortAudio is a free, cross-platform,
> open-source, audio I/O library.  It
> lets you write simple audio programs
> in 'C' or C++ that will compile and
> run on many platforms including
> Windows, Macintosh OS X, and Unix
> (OSS/ALSA). It is intended to promote
> the exchange of audio software between
> developers on different platforms.
> Many applications use PortAudio for
> Audio I/O.
>
> PortAudio provides a very simple API
> for recording and/or playing sound
> using a simple callback function or a
> blocking read/write interface. Example
> programs are included that play sine
> waves, process audio input (guitar
> fuzz), record and playback audio, list
> available audio devices, etc.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this, the tutorials are now at http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/tutorial_start.html

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/rdp/directshow-demo-audio-input-open-source might help, if you want to use directshow.